# Blank page for any new route in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.0 and been developing on this project for months without any problems. I just added a new route with a new method in the controller. But whatever I do, all these new entries in the routes.php file show me a blank page.

In my routes.php:

```
Route::get('dashboard/product_categories/testing', 'ProductCategoriesController@testing');
```

In the ProductCategoriesController.php:

```
public function testing() {
    die('Hello world!');
}
```

This happens to all new entries in the routes.php. No matter what controller its pointed to.

I do not use route:cache so am clueless where this problem stems from

Please note: This is an unchanged project. The httpd server is running as it should and the storage folders have read/write permissions

Comment: For my experience could be a ton of causes, but all of them can be found doing the following: 1. edit your .env file and set `DEBUG` to `true`, give write permissions to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Then, try again.

Comment: This is all intact and debug is on. The log files are also empty, so there is no error. It is really caused by some caching of routes????

Comment: I don't think so. What happen when you trigger `php artisan clear-compiled` and then `php artisan optimize`?

Comment: Tried that also and no change :(

Comment: try: composer dump-autoload

Comment: Also put `Route::get('dashboard/product_categories/testing', function(){ return "hello world"; });` and test it.

Comment: Panagiotis, tried it, no luck here also

Comment: Manix, no luck with that. Nothing is printed on screen

Comment: But it gets weird. When I add `index` to the path, like: `Route::get('dashboard/product_categories/index/testing', 'ProductCategoriesController@testing');` it works. This is very strange

Comment: check    routeServiceProvider file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I totally forgot about this question, but I found the solution: `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Then you have to manually delete the file `bootstrap/cache/routes.php`

Answer (score 9):

If you have a resource controller for the dashboard try to add the new routes before the resource.

Comment: thank you, that was extremely hard to find, clear didn't help.  Indeed I had to move it before my resource controller!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the answers helped.
My problem was with two routes matching each other.

A sample of my `web.php` file is below:

```
Route::get('user/{user}', 'UserController@show');
Route::get('user/restore, 'UserController@restore');
```

It took me a while to realise what was happening here.

Despite the fact that `$user` was typecast in my controller to an instance of `User`; I just assumed that the string `restore` would not match that route.

In the end, I realised that the string `restore` was being passed as a parameter to the route above and was, therefore, failing to match a User model.

To solve this I had to change the route to the following:

```
Route::get('user/{user}', 'UserController@show')->where('user', '\d+');
Route::get('user/restore, 'UserController@restore');
```

Now only numbers are matched to that route and the restore route works as expected.
The other solution would be to change the order but I didn't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting this before public function methods :

> @return \Illuminate\Http\Response